# Hide and show the navbar when scrolling up

Tags: javascript

I would like to improve an existing code that allows me to show the navbar once the page is loaded and after the user scrolls down it disappears. I want to make the navbar appear every time the user scrolls up. Basically, I need a [Headroom plugin](http://wicky.nillia.ms/headroom.js/), but as a pure javascript. I would consider any other simple alternatives.

That's is some HTML and the Javascript itself:

```js
//hide and show navbar when scrolled <100px
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {

    // hide .navbar first
    $(".navbar").show();

    // fade in .navbar
    $(function() {
      $(window).scroll(function() {
        // set distance user needs to scroll before we fadeIn navbar
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
          $('.navbar').fadeOut();
        } else {
          $('.navbar').fadeIn();
        }
      });


    });

  });
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header class="nav-down">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top container-fluid" id="navbar-exe" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-2">
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand logo page-scroll text-muted" href="#Home">VAYNER<span class="medialogo">MEDIA</span></a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbar-collapse-2">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#About" class="page-scroll">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Services" class="page-scroll">Contact</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
  </nav>
  <!-- /.navbar -->
</header>
```

Comment: Is there a problem with creating the CSS for headroom through your javascript? EDIT: Adding HTML `<style>` tag containing CSS

Comment: I don't quite understand what do you mean by that. Could please explain that?

Comment: You can programatically create HTML elements, including `<style>` elements containing CSS. This can be used to create the CSS styles required for headroom from pure javascript.

Comment: I am new to javascript. Could you please show me an example, because I can't see anything in it. Thx

Comment: I should have asked this first, but is there anything preventing you from using headroom?

Comment: yeah! For some reason, I can't install it...

Comment: What do you mean by "can't install it"? Can you not get it to load, or does it not do anything after being loaded? (Headroom requires some CSS to work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [headroom.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/headroom.js/) (the normal way) (not pure JS, but should work for OP):

Important notes:

- The header must be fixed to the top (Bootstrap navbar class
  `.navbar-fixed-top`)
- CSS styling required for headroom to do anything
  (it just adds/removes classes)
- If using jQuery plugin, the plugin must be loaded first (`jQuery.headroom.js`)

```js
var headroom = new Headroom(document.getElementById("navbar"));
headroom.init();
```

```css
.headroom {
    will-change: transform;
    transition: transform 200ms linear;
    
}
.headroom--pinned {
    transform: translateY(0%);
}
.headroom--unpinned {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/headroom.js@0.9.3/dist/headroom.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container">
  <h3>Ripped from W3Schools' Collapsible Navbar example</h3>
  <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam odio ex, convallis sit amet neque congue, mattis fermentum nunc. Nunc rutrum ex id massa maximus sodales. Aenean semper leo erat. Vivamus vitae vestibulum ex, sed imperdiet eros. Suspendisse pretium urna vel lacus faucibus porta. Mauris suscipit nec ipsum sed egestas. Mauris in dolor nulla. Suspendisse eleifend sit amet nisi et volutpat. Pellentesque mollis cursus eros sed hendrerit. Aliquam imperdiet fringilla fringilla. Sed elit dolor, gravida sollicitudin condimentum sollicitudin, eleifend lobortis dolor. Sed et felis commodo metus pretium condimentum ac eu tellus.
</p>
<p>
Proin volutpat nec ipsum venenatis vulputate. Aenean et erat a risus elementum mollis eu a neque. Integer congue orci tellus, sed mattis neque sollicitudin quis. Ut nec massa massa. Morbi eget aliquam urna. Etiam vitae eros id enim ultrices hendrerit. Quisque at arcu eros. Pellentesque at erat et sem imperdiet pharetra.
</p>
<p>
Suspendisse potenti. Phasellus vel leo nec ante feugiat suscipit sit amet quis nibh. Morbi at tempus nisi. Morbi posuere non sem sed mollis. Vestibulum a tellus nisl. Nunc mi augue, pharetra in congue sed, hendrerit eget neque. Proin rutrum, arcu non venenatis fermentum, justo nisl ultricies elit, ac congue ipsum dolor lobortis dui. Duis interdum sit amet enim vitae vestibulum. Duis tincidunt urna at lorem tristique molestie. Fusce mollis, diam ut rhoncus iaculis, tortor augue accumsan nisl, nec pharetra massa ligula ut erat. Praesent tincidunt leo quis pellentesque pellentesque. Praesent pellentesque magna in felis feugiat auctor euismod ac tortor.
</p>
<p>
Etiam interdum egestas consectetur. Fusce tincidunt, sapien finibus consequat eleifend, mauris libero varius nunc, eget suscipit ligula augue id est. Sed porta nisi vitae massa commodo ornare. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum dapibus leo dolor, nec porttitor eros viverra non. Vestibulum consequat nisl sed interdum dictum. Praesent ut nisi sed nibh feugiat consectetur a et risus. Integer euismod arcu sapien, vel molestie erat convallis vel. Suspendisse potenti.
</p><p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam odio ex, convallis sit amet neque congue, mattis fermentum nunc. Nunc rutrum ex id massa maximus sodales. Aenean semper leo erat. Vivamus vitae vestibulum ex, sed imperdiet eros. Suspendisse pretium urna vel lacus faucibus porta. Mauris suscipit nec ipsum sed egestas. Mauris in dolor nulla. Suspendisse eleifend sit amet nisi et volutpat. Pellentesque mollis cursus eros sed hendrerit. Aliquam imperdiet fringilla fringilla. Sed elit dolor, gravida sollicitudin condimentum sollicitudin, eleifend lobortis dolor. Sed et felis commodo metus pretium condimentum ac eu tellus.
</p>
<p>
Proin volutpat nec ipsum venenatis vulputate. Aenean et erat a risus elementum mollis eu a neque. Integer congue orci tellus, sed mattis neque sollicitudin quis. Ut nec massa massa. Morbi eget aliquam urna. Etiam vitae eros id enim ultrices hendrerit. Quisque at arcu eros. Pellentesque at erat et sem imperdiet pharetra.
</p>
<p>
Suspendisse potenti. Phasellus vel leo nec ante feugiat suscipit sit amet quis nibh. Morbi at tempus nisi. Morbi posuere non sem sed mollis. Vestibulum a tellus nisl. Nunc mi augue, pharetra in congue sed, hendrerit eget neque. Proin rutrum, arcu non venenatis fermentum, justo nisl ultricies elit, ac congue ipsum dolor lobortis dui. Duis interdum sit amet enim vitae vestibulum. Duis tincidunt urna at lorem tristique molestie. Fusce mollis, diam ut rhoncus iaculis, tortor augue accumsan nisl, nec pharetra massa ligula ut erat. Praesent tincidunt leo quis pellentesque pellentesque. Praesent pellentesque magna in felis feugiat auctor euismod ac tortor.
</p>
<p>
Etiam interdum egestas consectetur. Fusce tincidunt, sapien finibus consequat eleifend, mauris libero varius nunc, eget suscipit ligula augue id est. Sed porta nisi vitae massa commodo ornare. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum dapibus leo dolor, nec porttitor eros viverra non. Vestibulum consequat nisl sed interdum dictum. Praesent ut nisi sed nibh feugiat consectetur a et risus. Integer euismod arcu sapien, vel molestie erat convallis vel. Suspendisse potenti.
</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works if I create completely a new page. Your code is good. The question is, why it doesn't work on my webpage, even though I have no errors...

Comment: You can create a new question to figure out why your Headroom isn't working, with what you're currently doing to implement it. Right now, this question's comments are a bit of a mess ;)

Comment: agree.Anyways, your code is working well. The problem might be in the working with other scripts along.Thx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If creating HTML is allowed, one can add the CSS styles required for Headroom through Javascript.

**Note:** This only creates the CSS for Headroom; Headroom itself still must be loaded

Examples using CSS on [headroom.js examples](http://wicky.nillia.ms/headroom.js/)

Pure JS:

```js
var styleNode = document.createElement("style");
var cssNode = document.createTextNode('.headroom {\
    will-change: transform;\
    transition: transform 200ms linear;\
}\
.headroom--pinned {\
    transform: translateY(0%);\
}\
.headroom--unpinned {\
    transform: translateY(-100%);\
}');
styleNode.appendChild(cssNode);
document.head.appendChild(styleNode);
```

jQuery:

```js
$('<style/>', {
  text: '.headroom {\
will-change: transform;\
transition: transform 200ms linear;\
}\
.headroom--pinned {\
transform: translateY(0%);\
}\
.headroom--unpinned {\
transform: translateY(-100%);\
}'
}).appendTo('head');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So I can add to my website (navbar) either the pure JS or jQuery that you posted?

Comment: This simply adds the CSS required to make Headroom do anything, created through Javascript. You still need to load Headroom though. Updated my answer...

Comment: It doesn't work. Something it is not allowing it to work properly!

Comment: Did you initialize Headroom as per the instructions given on their website? and what errors are you receiving?

Comment: I did everything right I think.I loaded in the header the headroom.js. I added the pure JS from their website in the bottom of my website.The css I added  as well. Also, I added all needed classes to my elements. And nothing works. No error though.